# How to create connectors for Kafka-connect on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am deploying [Kafka-connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) using [cp-kafka-connect](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect) Helm chart in distributed mode.

A working Kafka cluster with broker and zookeeper is already running on the same GKE cluster. I understand I can create connectors by sending post requests to `http://localhost:8083/connectors` endpoint once it is available.
However, Kafka-connect container goes into RUNNING state and then starts loading the jar files and till all the jar files are loaded the endpoint mentioned above is unreachable.

I am looking for a way to automate the step of manually `exec` the pod, check if the endpoint is ready and then send the post requests. I have a shell script that has a bunch of `curl -X POST` requests to this endpoint to create the connectors and also have config files for these connectors which work fine with standalone mode (using Confluent platform show in this [confluent blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/)).

Now there are only two ways to create the connector:

1. Somehow identify when the container is actually ready (when the endpoint has started listening) and then run the shell script containing the curl requests
2. OR use the configuration files as we do in standalone mode (Example: `$ <path/to/CLI>/confluent local load connector_name -- -d /connector-config.json`)

Which of the above approach is better?

Is the second approach (config files) even doable with distributed mode?

- If ***YES:*** How to do that?
- If ***NO:*** How to successfully do what is explained in the first approach?

***EDIT:***
With reference to his [github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/467)(thanks to @cricket_007's answer below)  I added the following as the container command and connectors got created after the endpoint gets ready:

```
...
command:
  - /bin/bash
  - -c
  - |
    /etc/confluent/docker/run &
    echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on kafka-connect  "
    while : ; do
      curl_status=`curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://localhost:8083/connectors`
      echo -e `date` " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $curl_status " (waiting for 200)"
      if [ $curl_status -eq 200 ] ; then
        break
      fi
      sleep 5
    done
    echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Kafka Connector(s)"
    /tmp/scripts/create-connectors.sh
    sleep infinity
...
```

`/tmp/scripts/create-connectors.sh` is a script mounted externally containing a bunch of POST requests using CURL to the Kafka-connect API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confluent local` doesn't interact with a remote Connect cluster, such as one in Kubernetes.

Please refer to the [Kafka Connect REST API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest)

You'd connect to it like any other RESTful api running in the cluster (via a Nodeport, or an Ingress/API Gateway for example)

> the endpoint mentioned above is unreachable.

Localhost is the physical machine you're typing the commands into, not the remote GKE cluster

> Somehow identify when the container is actually ready

Kubernetes health checks are responsible for that

```
kubectl get services
```

> there are only two ways to create the connector

That's not true. You could additional run Landoop's Kafka Connect UI or Confluent Control Center in your cluster to point and click.

But if you have local config files, you could also write code to interact with the API

Or try and see if you can make a PR for this issue

https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/467

Comment: Most of the points mentioned in this answer are already there in the question itself. I understand the use of `confluent local` but as mentioned in the question, I am searching for a way to create the connectors using config files (in distributed mode) or maybe automate the step to 1. Check if the endpoint is reachable (because it takes some time to load the configurations), 2. If yes, then make the post requests. Would you mind elaborating the `if you have local config files, you could also write code to interact with the API` point please?

Comment: Bash? Something like `find configs/ -name "*.json" -exec curl -X POST -d@{} http://connect-k8s-svc:8083  \;`

Comment: Or write python, Java, etc. It's just http calls

Comment: But then the logic has to be there in the script with a `while loop` till the endpoint is reachable. That sounds like a hack to me somehow, I was looking for an elegant way to do this. "Through Kubernetes get to know that the endpoint is now ready and then run the script. It is possible in Kubernetes 1.16 with [startupProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes) but GKE 1.16 is not yet stable in GCP."

Comment: That's not a Connect server issue, that's a GKE problem... If you really wanted to hack it, you'd post kafka messages directly into the Connect configs topic rather than the rest api. Or see this issue I made https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/467

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the issue. I think to change the `command` var of the YAML manifest to wait for the endpoint to be ready infinitely and then start will do the trick. let me give that a try and let you know the result. Also, I am now interested to know what kind (format) of messages I would have to put inside the `config` topic in order to create the connectors. Would you mind shedding some light on that (or point to a documentation/issue)?

Comment: They're in JSON format. I've not actually done it before, but you're welcome to consume those internal topics at any point to inspect them